# Найти число из массива, которое встречается один раз

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, числа

Привет!  Есть массив из чисел  {3,4,3,4,5,8,9,8,9} найти число, которое встчается один раз.

Comment: @Mitzmeister, согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Не могу организовать поиска числа

Comment: таки уточните, что вы сделали сами

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int m[] = {3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 8, 9};
    int len = 9;
    map<int, int> counter;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        ++counter[m[i]];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        if (counter[m[i]] == 1)
            cout << m[i] << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Использовал STL.

Ещё такой способ, без STL, но за квадрат:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int m[] = {3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 8, 9};
    int len = 9;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j)
            if (i != j && m[i] == m[j])
                ++count;
        if (!count)
            cout << m[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в "квадратичном решении" во внутренний цикл можно чуть соптимизировать и записать так:

    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
       count += (m[i] == m[j]);
    // и тоогда изменим условие печати
    if (count == 1)
       ....

Answer (score 5):

Классическое решение этой задачи простое со сложностью O(n). Задача в том, что нужно проксорить все числа последовательно.

**внимание:** 
Данный алгоритм предполагает, что у всех чисел, кроме одного есть пары. Доказательство простое - так как xor - операция коммутативная, то аргументы можно переставлять. В связи с этим, можно переставить аргументы так, что бы они шли парами, а аргумент без пары - в самом конце. Так как xor двух одинаковых чисел равен нулю, то для любого количества пар одинаковых чисел он будет равен нулю. xor 0 и любого числа собственно равен самому числу.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int m[] = {3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 8, 9};
    int l = sizeof(m)/sizeof(m[0]);
    int r = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) r ^= m[i];
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

плюсы:

- линейная сложность
- не нужна дополнительная память. (ну кроме хранения счетчика и одного int'а для подсчета.
- поточность обработки.

для любителей нового стандарта:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    int m[] = {3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 8, 9};

    int r = std::accumulate(
        std::begin(m), std::end(m), 0,
        [](int x, int y){return x^y;}); 
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: этот алгоритм работает только при соблюдении двух условий - 

1. если в последовательности есть всего лишь одно число, встречающееся 1 раз. То есть он не сработает для { 3, 4, 3, 5 } 
2. если повторяющееся число повторяется четное количество раз. ТО есть не сработает для такой последовательности: { 3, 4, 3, 3 }

Comment: по условию задачи все числа, кроме одного повторяются два раза.

Comment: >по условию задачи все числа, кроме одного повторяются два раза

тем не менее, это нигде в условии не сказано явно

Comment: Да у меня даже для этой последовательности не сработало ))))

Comment: А вы ещё отрицательные числа не включали (хотя в условии их и нет). Там эффект от xor может быть ещё интересней.

Comment: У меня все сработало, и для отрицательных чисел все тоже будет работать правильно.

Comment: @alexlz честно говоря, я не нашел ситуации, в которой отрицательные числа ломали бы эту логику (при условии соблюдения двух условий, что я указал выше)

Comment: @DreamChild & @mikillskegg - спасибо за минусы:)
Запустите хотя бы код.

Comment: @KoVadim не обижайтесь, я в других вопросах вам три плюса поставлю, тем более, что обычно есть за что)  А что касается кода, то все, о чем я тут писал основано исключительно на результатах запуска и отладки - у меня в голове нет компилятора, поэтому критиковать чей-либо код только на том лишь основании, что "мне так кажется" я себе не позволяю. Поверьте, я запускал ваш код на разных наборах данных

Comment: на наборе {1,1,1,2} оно конечно не отработает. Это я знаю. Но это слишком классическая олимпиадная (и для собеседований) задача.

Comment: @KoVadim, код-то, конечно, работает. Только для набора чисел, когда

1. Число, которое встречается один раз ровно одно.

2. Все остальные числа встречаются четное число раз.

Довольно экзотично, но сама идея интересная. Навеяно RAID?

Comment: Странно. Утром код не отработал, сейчас отработал. Минус снимаю, но все равно он годен только для очень определенного набора входных данных. А так... остроумно.

Comment: @DreamChild на наборе {-1, 1} получаем результат -2. Правда тут мы имеем ситуацию, когда два числа встречаются нечётное число раз, а её уже обсуждали...

Comment: Никакие числа не могут «сломать» этот алгоритм:  

    A xor B xor B = A
Можно продолжать до бесконечности:  

    A xor B xor B xor C xor C ... = A
Это классическая загадка для программистов с классическим решением, которое описал @KoVadim.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а в чем загадка-то состоит?

Просто ведь: 0 xor 1 == 1, 1 xor 0 == 1, 0 xor 0 == 0, 1 xor 1 == 0.

Тогда очевидно, что B xor B == 0, т.к. все биты одинаковые.

Также понятно, что A xor 0 == A (пояснение требуется?).


Следовательно: B xor B xor B xor B ... четное число раз == 0

и значит результат A xor (B xor B xor B xor B ... четное число раз) == A.

Все.

Comment: @avp, загадка в том, что надо найти это простое и красивое решение.

Comment: > Дан достаточно большой входной поток целых чисел, в котором все числа встречаются ровно 2 раза, кроме одного, которое входит только 1 раз. Нужно за конечное число проходов O(1) потока (массива) и используя дополнительной памяти не более O(1) найти его.  

(C) braingames.ru

Answer (score 4):

Есть классическое решение. Сортируем последовательность, использую любую эффективную сортировку. Потом в один проход находим искомое число.

Comment: Плохой способ. Большая сложность.

Comment: Сложность чего?

Comment: большая О. За деталями - смотрите мой ответ.

Comment: @KoVadim есть некоторые основания полагать, что чуваку, вопрос которого тут обсуждается, весьма безразличны проблемы сложности алгоритма, а чудеса с xor-ом и уж тем более новым стандартом не поймет даже его препод

Comment: для java программистов не знать xor - это простительно. Для С++ - гнать в шею. А код под новый стандарт я добавил для любителей. Они здесь есть.

Comment: @KoVadim ИМХО любому прогеру не знать `xor` непростительно (я не говорю об HTML верстальщиках и 1С мучениках)

Comment: простите, а кто вам сказал, что ТС является C++ программистом? Куда более вероятно, что это первокурсник, которому нужно сделать лабу

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class m_pair{
public:
  int value;
  int count;
};

void print(vector<m_pair> & v){
  int size = v.size();

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      cout << v[i].value << "\t" << v[i].count << endl;
  }
}

void add(vector<m_pair> & v, int & value){
  int size = v.size();
  m_pair p;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      if (v[i].value == value){
          v[i].count += 1;
          return;
      }
  }

  p.value = value;
  p.count = 1;
  v.push_back(p);
}

bool check(vector<m_pair> & v){ // возвращет истину если есть ошибка или нет одинарных значений
  int size = v.size();
  bool result = true;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      if ((v[i].count == 1) && (result)){
          result = false;
          continue;
      }

      if ((v[i].count == 1) && (!result))
        return true; // несколько одинарных значений
  }

  return result; // нет одинарных  значений
}

int one(vector<m_pair> & v){
  int size = v.size();

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      if (v[i].count == 1){
          return v[i].value;
      }
  }
}

int main() {
    int m[] = {3, 1, 1,  4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 8, 9, 7, 9, 1}; // массив с ошибкой
    vector<m_pair> v;
    int size = sizeof(m) / sizeof(m[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        add(v, m[i]);

    print(v);

    if (check(v)){
        cout << "ошибка в массиве" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "число " << one(v) << " встречается один раз." << endl;
    }

    cout << "___________________________________________" << endl;

    int a[] = {3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 8, 9}; // правильный массив
    size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    v.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        add(v, a[i]);

    print(v);

    if (check(v)){
        cout << "ошибка в массиве" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "число " << one(v) << " встречается один раз." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @perfect, а Вы ответ @nicolai с `map` видели?

IMHO значительно элегантней. 

Вообще, если отнестись формально  условию задачи (*найти* ***число***), то можно сделать вариант с `std::set`.

Comment: Это решение очень веселое. Создание `std::map` и `std::pair` с квадратичной сложностью... Терпеливый и упорный человек.

Comment: плюс этого кода в том что можно использовать любой тип в m_pair и этот код будет работать с любым типом или объектом у которого есть перегруженный оператор сравнения. например нам надо получить слово встречающего однажды в тексте: 

    class m_pair{
    public:
    string value;
    int count;
    };

хотя можно использовать и стандартный тип pair но я не хотел с ним заморачиватся

@Kovadim на код потратил 10 минут так что мучился недолго )